# Применение команды rollback в PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Изучаю работу с PostgreSQL с помощью Python DB-API psycopg2. Дошел до команды cur.rollback(). В теории понятно,что делает но практического применения в сети не нашел.Может ли кто-нибудь скинуть кусок кода,который бы показал на практике применение данного метода.Буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: это может быть полезно, если вам надо подряд выполнить несколько действий в БД и надо гарантировать, что выполняться либо все эти действия либо ни одно из них. Тогда (при выключенном на соединении autocommit) вы выполняете ваши действия и в случае обнаружения каких либо ошибок вызываете rollback() что бы ничего из выполненного в БД не сохранилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный метод откатит изменения текущей транзакции:

```
conn.autocommit = False
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test()")
cur.rollback()
```

После выполнения таблица с названием test не будет создана.
Если сделать так:

```
conn.autocommit = False
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test()")
cur.commit()
```

то таблица будет создана. 
Тоже касается любых операций от начала до окончания транзакции.
Мануал по транзакциям [тут](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/tutorial-transactions)

Comment: В чем разница между приведенными фрагментами кода?

Comment: `autocommit=True` во 2 случае

Comment: Разница в ошибке)) Исправил